# c# change file name of relative or absolute uri

Tags: c#, .net, url

I'm looking for a clean method of changing the filename of an absolute or relative uri, that may contain multiple segments. We don't know if its absolute or relative in advance, so we need to detect that:

Here's the test case:

```
    [Test]
    public void Can_change_path_file_name()
    {
        Fix("file.txt").ShouldEqual("file_fixed.txt");
        Fix("/file.txt").ShouldEqual("/file_fixed.txt");
        Fix("directory/file.txt").ShouldEqual("directory/file_fixed.txt");
        Fix("/directory/file.txt").ShouldEqual("/directory/file_fixed.txt");
        Fix("/directory/subdirectory/file.txt").ShouldEqual("/directory/subdirectory/file_fixed.txt");
        Fix("http://www.test.com/directory/subdirectory/file.txt").ShouldEqual("http://www.test.com/directory/subdirectory/file_fixed.txt");
        Fix("/directory/file/file.txt").ShouldEqual("/directory/file/file_fixed.txt");
    }

    private string Fix(string uri)
    {
       // fill me with goodness
    }
```

My solution works but seems a bit involved. I've posted it below in case you want to better it:

```
private string Fix(string uri)
{
    var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(uri);
    var extension = Path.GetExtension(uri);
    fileName += "_fixed" + extension;

    var path = uri.Contains('/') ? uri.Substring(0, uri.LastIndexOf('/') + 1) : "";
    return Combine(path, fileName);
}

private string Combine(string path1, string path2)
{
    if (path1 == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("path1");
    }

    if (path2 == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("path2");
    }

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(path2))
    {
        return path1;
    }

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(path1))
    {
        return path2;
    }

    if (path2.StartsWith("http://") || path2.StartsWith("https://"))
    {
        return path2;
    }

    var ch = path1[path1.Length - 1];

    if (ch != '/')
    {
        return (path1.TrimEnd('/') + '/' + path2.TrimStart('/'));
    }

    return (path1 + path2);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not a simple string replace?

```
private string Fix(string uri)
{
    var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(uri);
    var extension = Path.GetExtension(uri);

    return uri.Replace(string.Format("{0}{1}", fileName, extension), string.Format("{0}_fixed{1}", fileName, extension));
}
```

This would only go wrong in case your filename will also occur in some other segment of the uri.

Another option that does not have this drawback is:

```
private string Fix(string uri)
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(uri);
        var extension = Path.GetExtension(uri);
        var slashIndex = uri.LastIndexOf("/");

        return string.Format("{0}{1}_fixed{2}", uri.Substring(0, slashIndex + 1), fileName, extension);
    }
```

Comment: @SLaks - is this a regular expression? You've got +2 so I assume its something useful??

Comment: @SLaks - Yes that's why I said it would go wrong in that case. Maybe the OP knows in advance if this situation would occur.

Comment: @Ben: It's a sample path.  I was pointing the drawback that Quimcia just mentioned.

Comment: Ah okay, makes sense now. @Quimica - no I don't know in advance. This is partly my original solution ended up being so involved. Changing the file name wasn't a problem, it was reattaching it to the original url.

Comment: @Ben well in that case the second option should work for you.

Comment: +1 - Sure does. Also works with filenames without extensions which is good.

Comment: btw, you need to remove the "." from fixed.{2} as the GetExtension method includes the "."

Answer (score 4):

No regular expressions, no string indexes.

Just using .NET `Path` methods to retreive, and reassemble, a new filename:

```
/// <summary>
/// Partner to Path.ChangeExtension. This function changes the base filename portion
/// </summary>
/// <param name="path"></param>
/// <param name="newFilename"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static String ChangeFilename(String path, String newFilename)
{
   String directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(path); //e.g. "C:\Temp\foo.dat" ==> "C:\Temp"
   //String oldFilename = Path.GetFileName(path); //e.g. "C:\Temp\foo.dat" ==> "foo.dat"
   //String filenameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path); //e.g. "C:\Temp\foo.dat" ==> "foo"
   String extension = Path.GetExtension(path); //e.g. "C:\Temp\foo.dat" ==> ".dat"

   //Reassemble as
   //    directoryName \ newFilename dotExtension
   return String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}",
         directoryName, 
         Path.DirectorySeparatorChar,
         newFilename,
         extension);
}
```

> **Note**: Any code is released into the public domain. No attribution required.

Answer (score 1):

How about some Regular Expression like

```
\b[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

This should find all endings of `file` followed by an extension.

Next, if you capture the `file`...

```
\b([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)$
```

...you then can [replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace.aspx) it:

```
var result = Regex.Replace( 
    input,
    @"\b([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)$",
    "$1_fixed$2" );
```

and you're done. You could use an online Regular Expression tester like [this one](http://www.fileformat.info/tool/regex.htm) to test before you code.

Comment: I won't know the file name in advance. Essentially I need to append some text onto the end of a filename (before the extension)

Comment: @Ben - I adjusted my example.

Comment: I've updated my test to include one for duplicate directory/file segments. Your code passes +1

Answer (score 1):

I've wrapped the working solution into a utility method. Should be some help to others.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Changes the file name of the <paramref name="uri"/> using the given <paramref name="modifier"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="uri">A relative or absolute uri</param>
    /// <param name="modifier">A function to apply to the filename</param>
    /// <returns>The modified uri</returns>
    public static string ModifyUriFileName(string uri, Func<string, string> modifier)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(uri))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("uri");
        }

        var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(uri);
        var extension = Path.GetExtension(uri);
        var path = uri.Substring(0, uri.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);

        return string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", path, modifier(fileName), extension);
    }
```

Usage:

`return CommonUtils.ModifyUriFileName(uri, s => s + "_fixed");`